# Can't get blender to work on Ubuntu - when it opens I don't see the default scene

Tags: linux, installation

I have recently installed Blender on Ubuntu. I have tried both installing v 2.72 by downloading the tar from the website and 2.62 installed using apt-get.

In both cases when I open Blender I do not see the default image (mesh floor, cube, light). These objects seemingly exist (I can seethe cube in render mode) but I am unable to see them or add other meshes I can see.

I've previously used Blender on Windows and haven't experienced this.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Update. If I start blender from it's folder using

./blender-softwaregl

it works, I can then see the mesh floor, box, lamp etc. Found this here:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/Linux/Debian_Ubuntu

So looks like a graphics hardware driver issue...

Comment: What kind of GPU are you using? Are you using the proprietary drivers for it?

Comment: I have recently bought a Dell XPS13 with Ubuntu. It has a Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller. I don't have any proprietary drivers installed - should I?

Comment: In blender reset everything by going to file-> load factory setting this might help

Comment: @daniel, have tried it, no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: You could add your update as an answer this could to be helpful to users.

Comment: This could be a bug so I think you may report it.

Comment: You should definitely update the graphics controller drivers if you have the option.  The fact that it's working using softwareGL is a good indicator that it's a driver problem.

Comment: @stacker I don't think this would be a complete answer  since using ./blender-softwaregl is forcing Blender's OpenGL calls to run on the CPU instead of the GPU.  When doing this, performance of the viewport could easily be 100 times slower since CPU's don't handle OpenGL/DirectX API calls very well at all.

Comment: Check your OpenGL intallation. It should be compatible to the blender Version.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`  and `glxinfo | egrep -i "direct rendering|OpenGL core profile"`. There might be newer drivers at ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa  but you probably want to head over to [http://askubuntu.com/](http://askubuntu.com/).